# Meaning of a notation of interget set on another set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

What's the meaning of X = {0,1}$^\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: The set of [functions from $\mathbb Z$ to $\{ 0,1 \}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set#Representing_subsets_as_functions). Every such function coresponds to a subset of $\mathbb Z$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the set of mappings $\{f\mid f:\Bbb Z\rightarrow\{0,1\}\}$, or the set of denumerable sequences labeled by the integers with values in the set $\{0,1\}$ (binary sequences).